# Virtual Box 3.0.2 Networking

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Vista x64 Host and an Ubuntu Guest.

From my host I would like to access my Ubuntu Guest via its IP address.
From my Ubuntu Guest I would like to access my Vista Host and the Internets.

Theoretically, I should be able to just enable "Bridged Adapter" networking for my adapter and all should be well.

But its not.

Has anyone managed to get this working, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work around this, by changing the networking to use the "Intel Pro/1000 network driver", so far so good.

This may be a bug in 3.0.2 with Vista x64, who knows.

Comment: Sometimes bridging doesn't work with wifi adapters, though it may have only been a problem wither earlier cards/drivers.

Comment: Its not a wifi adapter, in fact it seem to work ... if I enable it with other adapters, by its self it refuses to work.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both machines are getting different and valid IP addresses from the network this should work. However make sure you have the VirtualBox Guest Additions installed. If not I would look at:

- Firewall Settings

I would assume you can successfully ping the host from the guest and the other way around.

The other option is to use Shared Folders, which allows you to access host directly.

Also check that you have bound the Virtual Machine to the correct network card. This is relevant especially when you have Wireless.

- Virtual Machine Settings
- Network
- Adapter 1 (Select the one you are using)
- Adapter Type: (Leave as is)
- Attached to: Bridged Adapter
- Name: **(Select the correct physical card here)**

Also make sure the information box is not giving a big red error at this point.

Comment: I can not ping my guest from my host, and it refuses to get an ip address from my dhcp server, if i assign manually it does not work as well

Comment: Have you got the VirtualBox Guest Additions installed? Have you configured VirtualBox to bind to the correct network card?

Comment: Also I assume you have restarted the VM after the change?

Comment: See my answer, I worked around it. I don't know why but no matter what I did bridged refused to work, so I use NAT + Host only instead and all is good.